# How many reps are necessary to make a good abdomen?

Tags: fat, abdominals

I have read that doing 30 minutes of cardio consumes several energy, and doing more than 30 minutes burns fat.

How many reps of cardio activity do you suggest to make my abdomen hard?
Also how many minutes of cardio do you recommend. I have these measurements:

```
Eaist:  92.9  cm
Hip:    103.5 cm
Weight:  79.5 kg
Height: 1.77  m
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 parts to having good abs. First you need the muscle there, so that means core exercises like sit-ups, crunches, planks and medicine ball work.

Second, you need to remove the fat. The more muscle you have the more fat it will burn but you'll want to look closely at your diet and how many calories you taking in versus what you are burning. You need to burn more than you take in to lose fat.

One last thing, doing ab exercises doing ab exercises doesn't burn fat from your abs. All working out burns fat from everywhere.