# burn arm fat not feasible in my case

Tags: fat, arms

All my life I have been doing exercise (running, jogging, swimming, dancing, basket ball, martial arts, and gym stuff)

I know there are many genetic factors that make me almost impossible to reduce the fat in my arms. Some guy told me that I have water instead of fat, Nowadays I can not do exercise everyday (a couple of times per week).

How to burn that fat?.

```
My weight - 50 Kg
My height - 1.60 meters
```

I am a skinny person, but the issue here is the fat in my arms.

Comment: Did you lose 17cm and 30kg since last year? http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3824/how-many-reps-are-necessary-to-make-a-good-abdomen

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not feasible to target fat loss. [Spot reduction is a myth](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/3933/1771). You need to lose fat all over. The good news: fixing your diet and increasing exercise works well for this goal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can burn fat just in your arms, and it doesn't seem like you're overweight anyway. Why do you want to get rid of the arm fat? It probably doesn't matter. If it's for aesthetics, you'd probably do better to just try to add muscle, which would firm up your arms despite the fat that is on them.